# Android App - Xamarin - C# - How to return multiple integer variable values back to main activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to return multiple integer variable values from a second activity to the main activity, In the second activity I have a number of variables which are calculated through different functions which I need to return to the main activity to be added onto the total of another variable.

In my main activity I have started the second activity using StartActivityForResult

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAddItems).Click += delegate
        {
            var getMoreItems = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
            StartActivityForResult(getMoreItems,0);
        };
```

In the second activity I am attempting to return the values using PutExtra and an Intent, there are 7 integer variables and one string I am trying to return.

```
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnReturnItems).Click += delegate
        {
            Intent returnItems = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            string addOrSub = "add";
            returnItems.PutExtra("putAddOrSub", addOrSub);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar1", int1);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar2", int2);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar3", int3);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar4", int4);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar5", int5);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar6", int6);
            returnItems.PutExtra("putVar7", int7);
            SetResult(Result.Ok, returnItems);
            Finish();
        };
```

Im not entirely sure, but I think my problem lies within my OnActivityResult override back on my main activity.  First of all I tried

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                string addOrSub = data.GetStringExtra("putAddOrSub");
                if (addOrSub == "add")
                {
                    int tmpInt1 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar1");
                    int tmpInt2 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar2");
                    int tmpInt3 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar3");
                    int tmpInt4 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar4");
                    int tmpInt5 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar5");
                    int tmpInt6 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar6");
                    int tmpInt7 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar7");
                    updInt1 += tmpInt1;
                    updInt2 += tmpInt2;
                    updInt3 += tmpInt3;
                    updInt4 += tmpInt4;
                    updInt5 += tmpInt5;
                    updInt6 += tmpInt6;
                    updInt7 += tmpInt7;
                    anotherFunction();

                }
            }
        }
```

I was unable to run that because I recieved the error

"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'defaultValue' of 'Intent.GetIntExtra(string, int)'"

I decided to try adding a Convert.ToInt32 and changed to a GetStringExtra command, because I assume it for some reason is returning the data as a string.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                string addOrSub = data.GetStringExtra("putAddOrSub");
                if (addOrSub == "add")
                {
                    int tmpInt1 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar1"));
                    int tmpInt2 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar2"));
                    int tmpInt3 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar3"));
                    int tmpInt4 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar4"));
                    int tmpInt5 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar5"));
                    int tmpInt6 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar6"));
                    int tmpInt7 = Convert.ToInt32(data.GetStringExtra("putVar7"));
                    updInt1 += tmpInt1;
                    updInt2 += tmpInt2;
                    updInt3 += tmpInt3;
                    updInt4 += tmpInt4;
                    updInt5 += tmpInt5;
                    updInt6 += tmpInt6;
                    updInt7 += tmpInt7;
                    anotherFunction();

                }
            }
        }
```

Now I can run this in the Android Emulator, but it seems that there are no values being returned and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Please help!!
Excuse my noobyness, this is my first attempt at an android app and I've been struggling with this problem for the last 5 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'defaultValue' of 'Intent.GetIntExtra(string, int)'

`GetIntExtra` requires two parameters:

> name   String: The name of the desired item.
>
> defaultValue   int: the value to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given name.

Example: If `putVar1` does not exist, what is the value you want returned by default:

```
int tmpInt1 = data.GetIntExtra("putVar1", 0);
```

Docs: [getIntExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int))